# No puedo instalar nada en ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Cuando quiero instalar alguna app en ubuntu 16.04 me lanza el mismo error, por ejemplo quiero instalar **Wine** y me dice esto:

```
jp@JP:/var/www/html/ebook$ sudo sudo apt install wine-stable
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt-get -f install» para corregirlo:
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
mysql-server : Depende: mysql-server-5.7 pero no va a instalarse
 wine-stable : Depende: wine64 (>= 1.8.5-1ubuntu2) pero no va a instalarse o
                    wine32 (>= 1.8.5-1ubuntu2)
           Depende: wine64 (< 1.8.5-1ubuntu2.1~) pero no va a instalarse o
                    wine32 (< 1.8.5-1ubuntu2.1~)
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt-get -f install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
```

**Siempre tengo el musmo error de mysql**

Comment: ¿Y ya intentaste hacer lo que dice apt: `sudo apt -f install`. Es probable que no haya terminado la instalación de ese paquete, por ejemplo, que no haya concluido la configuración, así que se tiene que ejecutar esa parte del script.

Comment: ¿Y esta pregunta que tiene que ver con programación?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque corresponde a la temática del sitio

Answer (score 2):

Ejecuta estos comandos:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get autoclean; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -f install;
```

Esto debería resolver el problema. Si así no fuera por favor edita la pregunta y agrega nueva información.

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta `sudo apt-get -f install` en la terminal. Si no te funciona, debes averiguar la versión de mysql-server que es compatible con wine-stable e instalarlo.